# Loaded external jquery mobile page not working

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

i'm trying to load an external jquery mobile page in a div but seems not to work.

index.html

```
    <div data-role="page" id="page1">
  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>Header</h1>
  </div>
  <p><a class="followclick" href="#">Get the News</a></p>
  <div id="content" data-role="content"></div>
  <div data-role="footer">
    <h4>Footer</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.followclick').on('click', function(event) {
        $('#content').load('news.php');

    });
});
```

news.php

```
<div data-role="page" id="page2">
  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>Header</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="news" data-role="content"></div>
  <div data-role="footer">
    <h4>Footer</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: where is your '.followclick' element?

Comment: i just edited the question. its in

Answer (score 0):

Try using `jQuery.ajax({url:'news.php',type:'GET',success:function(resp){$('#content').html(resp);}})` instead.

`jQuery.load(....)` may not work with div.

jQuery load will work on any element associated with a URL: images, scripts, frames, iframes, and the window object.  It will also not work/give problems with cross domain requests.

[More info here](https://api.jquery.com/load-event/).

Hope this helps! Please mark as answer if it does! Thanks